# Cancel a dialog after a specific time of no user activity

Tags: c#, session, task, botframework

I have the following code to cancel a dialog in botframework, after the specific time that user does not have any activity and conversation with bot. I've store the cancellation token and try to load from the user data.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        try
        {
            // load and store the cancellation token
            StateClient stateClient = activity.GetStateClient();
            BotData userData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);
            if (userData.GetProperty<CancellationTokenSource>("TokenSource") == null)
            {
                userData.SetProperty("TokenSource", new CancellationTokenSource());
                await stateClient.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);
            }
            else
            {
                // cancel task here
                var token = userData.GetProperty<CancellationTokenSource>("TokenSource");
                token.Cancel();
                userData.SetProperty("TokenSource", new CancellationTokenSource());
                await stateClient.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);
            }
            userData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);
            var source = userData.GetProperty<CancellationTokenSource>("TokenSource");

            // start task
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(60000);
                // reset the dialog states
                using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity))
                {
                    var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
                    await botData.LoadAsync(default(CancellationToken));
                    var stack = scope.Resolve<IDialogStack>();
                    stack.Reset();
                    await botData.FlushAsync(default(CancellationToken));
                }
            }, source.Token);
        }
        catch(Exception) { throw;}
    }
}
```

The problem is the ran task cannot be stopped anymore.
Therefore, the question is how can I stopped the ran task in botframework (for each user)?

Comment: Can you please check this [code](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botFramework-proactiveMessages) which I guess might help you.

Comment: @Jyo Could you reference to a specific file? I cannot find any related code there.

Answer (score -1):

You only provide the CancellationToken to the Task.Run function, which only affects the start of the task, i.e. the token is only used to determine if the task start should be aborted when the token is cancelled.

The Task.Run function seemingly serves no function as the contained code is already asynchronous, i.e. await Task.Run(innerMethodBlock) should be replaced by just executing "innerMethodBlock" directly. To abort the actual code you need to provide the token in the places where you wrote default(CancellationToken) as default(CancellationToken) equals CancellationToken.None. Also "await Task.Delay(60000)" should be replaced by "await Task.Delay(60000, token)" too, although I don't know why you would want to wait 1 minute before you start initializing the bot state.

catch(Exception) { throw; } is also unnecessary code without a function.

Comment: All things have been done before. None of these are my answer.